# help setting Sql server 2005 security

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security

I am new to SQL Server, and I have been tasked with setting permissions on a remote server.  What I need to do is limit the domain admin from having access to any of the DB's on a particular server.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove BUILTIN/Administrators from the SA group.

Answer (score 1):

**Important!** Before you do this make absolutley sure you have either:

- the password for the "sa" account
  or
- your domain account is a member of the sysadmin server role

Otherwise you might find yourself locked out of the server.. not that this has ever happened to me.. ;-)

Comment: Oops well it worked and I was locked out which wasnt too bad becase I was supposed to be locked out.  Whew